# SAML not working across computers

Tags: security, tomcat, ssl, key, saml

I have a SAML web application. I have put its war in a tomcat, and can run it. It works perfectly locally, the endpoint is set to localhost. However, when I copy the entire tomcat directory to another machine, it does not work.

Essentially, I am asking what could vary between 2 machines that would affect tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out - I needed to install the Java Cryptography Extension on my computer. (Best solution is to install it into ALL of your JDKs/JREs and that way it will definitely work).